# Most efficient js/jquery way to prevent submission of empty fields (including spaces)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an advanced search form in a custom CMS. I need to check to make sure that the user doesn't try to submit the form without at least one field populated. No problem; this is a very stripped-down version:

```
var noText = false;

if(!$('#advancedId').val() && !$('#advancedTitle').val() && 
    $('#advancedCoupon').val() && !$('#advancedDesc').val() ) {
     noText = true;
}


if(noText) {
    alert("You haven't provided any search terms. Please fill in/select at least one field.");
    noText = false;
    return false;
}
```

But we have that one QA guy who just has to really do his job, and deliberately tries searches that there's no way our client would ever do. He submitted a bug indicating that if he entered a space in every field, it passes and tries to submit.

So I tried trimming the values like this:

```
if(!$('#advancedId').val().trim() && !$('#advancedTitle').val().trim() && 
    $('#advancedCoupon').val().trim() && !$('#advancedDesc').val().trim() ) {
    noText = true;
}
```

This of course works if I actually enter a space in all of the fields, but throws a "Cannot read property 'trim' of null" error if I try to submit it with a space in one field, and nothing in the others.

Yes, I could do something like this:

```
if($('#advancedId').val()) {
   $('#advancedId').val($('#advancedId').val().trim());
}
```

Yes, I could make it somewhat shorter with a terniary, but I'd still have to do that for over a dozen fields. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: required="true"

Comment: @KevinB - I don't want to force a specific field to be required, though - I just need to make sure that at least one of a dozen fields has a valid (i.e. non-space) value before submitting.

Comment: Does this have to work in old browsers? If not, maybe the pattern HTML attribute might be helpful - you could specify a regex to prevent the content being just whitespace, and I'd be surprised if there isn't a shim for that to make it work in older browsers.

Comment: @RolandStarke - no, it doesn't mean the input doesn't exist - it means there's no value in it - the null is from the `.val()` part. That's the whole point. I need a way to check to see if a field has any value at all, and then check to see if that value is only a space. I was hoping to find a better way to do it than what I already have, which, contrary to what you're suggesting, *does* work.

Comment: Just create an array of your field-id's and loop over them (var fields 
 = ['fieldid1',  'fieldid2', etc], then fields.foreach(function (item) { //call your validation function and use item as selector like this: $('#' + item).val(); })

Comment: And what's up with the downvotes? I don't think it's particularly stupid to ask for help about a better way to do something.

Comment: @EmmyS http://api.jquery.com/val/ i see there is a way to return `null` but only for select-multiple.  for text inputs it should always be an string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably select them all and then do a filter.  Though to make it less tightly coupled, I'd probably put a class on them and select with that instead of all the ids.

```js
//select all the fields concerned and filter on them for non-blank values
var nonBlankFields = $('#advancedId, #advancedTitle, #advancedCoupon, #advancedDesc').filter(function(){
  //default to an empty string if for some reason the value doesn't exist
  return ( this.value || '' ).trim().length > 0
});

if (!nonBlankFields.length) {
    alert("You haven't provided any search terms. Please fill in/select at least one field.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this is what I needed.